# Entity Framework 4.1.Code First. Automatically populating entities by ID

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I have a complex object graph which is just a set of stubs ie POCO types with an Id, which are freshly created and not attached to the context. These match up (by Id) with items already in the database. I am expecting EF to offer a means of 'hydrating' all of these stubs recursively... what's the mantra?

Comment: Did you try `dbContext.HydrateStubs(myStubGraph)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the properties are `virtual` this works as expected.

Comment: popular question on `virtual` for EF: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597760/what-effects-can-the-virtual-keyword-have-in-entity-framework-4-1-poco-code-fi