# Why use 'virtual' for class properties in Entity Framework model definitions?

Tags: c#, class, properties, virtual

In the following blog: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/16/code-first-development-with-entity-framework-4.aspx

The blog contains the following code sample:

```
public class Dinner
{
   public int DinnerID { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }
   public string Address { get; set; }
   public string HostedBy { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<RSVP> RSVPs { get; set; }
}

public class RSVP
{
   public int RsvpID { get; set; }
   public int DinnerID { get; set; }
   public string AttendeeEmail { get; set; }
   public virtual Dinner Dinner { get; set; }
}
```

What is the purpose of using `virtual` when defining a property in a class?  What effect does it have?

Comment: Are you asking to understand the general purpose of the 'virtual' keyword in C# or how it pertains specifically to Entity Framework?

Comment: @M.Babcock: I am asking what the purpose is as it pertains to properties, because I have never seen this before.

Comment: If you are familiar with how the virtual keyword affects polymorphism in methods then it is the same for properties.

Comment: Was the purpose of your question not to understand the general purpose of the 'virtual' keyword in C#?

Comment: @M.Babcock: no, because I am familiar with its use with methods in that it allows the method to be overriden. It just didn't make sense to me why anyone would want to override a property.

Comment: @M.Babcock: how could I have made it more evident?  The question is titled "Why use 'virtual' for properties in classes?".

Comment: @Gary - getter / setter properties are actually statically compiled into methods. So they're not traditional class fields such as 'public virtual Dinner';

Answer (score 312, accepted):

It allows the Entity Framework to create a proxy around the virtual property so that the property can support lazy loading and more efficient change tracking. See [What effect(s) can the virtual keyword have in Entity Framework 4.1 POCO Code First?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597760/what-effects-can-the-virtual-keyword-have-in-entity-framework-4-1-poco-code-fi) for a more thorough discussion.

**Edit to clarify "create a proxy around":**
By "create a proxy around", I'm referring specifically to what the Entity Framework does. The Entity Framework requires your navigation properties to be marked as virtual so that lazy loading and efficient change tracking are supported. See [Requirements for Creating POCO Proxies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/dd468057(v=vs.100)).
The Entity Framework uses inheritance to support this functionality, which is why it requires certain properties to be marked virtual in your base class POCOs. It literally creates new types that derive from your POCO types. So your POCO is acting as a base type for the Entity Framework's dynamically created subclasses. That's what I meant by "create a proxy around".

The dynamically created subclasses that the Entity Framework creates become apparent when using the Entity Framework at runtime, not at static compilation time. And only if you enable the Entity Framework's lazy loading or change tracking features. If you opt to never use the lazy loading or change tracking features of the Entity Framework (which is not the default), then you needn't declare any of your navigation properties as virtual. You are then responsible for loading those navigation properties yourself, either using what the Entity Framework refers to as "eager loading", or manually retrieving related types across multiple database queries. You can and should use lazy loading and change tracking features for your navigation properties in many scenarios though.

If you were to create a standalone class and mark properties as virtual, and simply construct and use instances of those classes in your own application, completely outside of the scope of the Entity Framework, then your virtual properties wouldn't gain you anything on their own.

**Edit to describe why properties would be marked as virtual**

Properties such as:

```
 public ICollection<RSVP> RSVPs { get; set; }
```

Are not fields and should not be thought of as such. These are called getters and setters, and at compilation time, they are converted into methods.

```
//Internally the code looks more like this:
public ICollection<RSVP> get_RSVPs()
{
    return _RSVPs;
}

public void set_RSVPs(RSVP value)
{
    _RSVPs = value;
}

private RSVP _RSVPs;
```

That's why they're marked as virtual for use in the Entity Framework; it allows the dynamically created classes to override the internally generated `get` and `set` functions. If your navigation property getter/setters are working for you in your Entity Framework usage, try revising them to just properties, recompile, and see if the Entity Framework is able to still function properly:

```
 public virtual ICollection<RSVP> RSVPs;
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'create a proxy around'? What is actually going on here?

Comment: Hi Gary, I revised my answer to clarify what I mean by "create a proxy around". Hope that helps a bit.

Comment: Saying "properties... are not properties" is quite unhelpful.  All properties are implemented as getter and/or setter methods, so it makes no sense to say "this property is really a getter and setter method not a property".

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Ben, I should have clarified that "properties are not fields". Let me know if you have any other feedback or questions.

Comment: I changed the wording and added another code example to help explain the "properties are not properties" a little better, please roll back if you do not want it.

Comment: +1 for trying to answer, rather blame a questioner for less knowing about virtual. "Unfortunately i see some users with high reputation thinks about their-self like as programming god!"

Comment: @ShanPlourde Does leaving property without `virtual` key word can screw up something. When do we know which one should be virtual in MVC?

Comment: @ShanPlourde, do we need to declare other properties like DinnerID, Title as Virtual. If yes then what would be the reason here?

Comment: @manaskumar I don't think we need other properties like DinnerId, Title as Virtual. You only need to declare navigation related properties and collections as virtual I believe.

Comment: I'm glad you changed the answer to include what you meant by create proxy around. This is very helpful!

Comment: nice answer... but shouldn't it be `private ICollection<RSVP> _RSVPs;` in your example?

Comment: @ShanPlourde "... only need navigation properties and collections as virtual". In your answer, you mentioned dynamic change tracking. My understanding was that dynamic change tracking (which is relevant for all properties, not just navigation), relies on the properties being declared virtual. If you don't, EF resorts to "snapshot" change tracking which is much less efficient as it has to compare values of every property between snapshots to find any changes.

Comment: should we apply the virtual keyword to the collections or also for the "single" class properties (as `User Creator {get; set;}` by eg)

Answer (score 75):

The `virtual` keyword in C# enables a method or property to be overridden by child classes. For more information please refer to [the MSDN documentation on the 'virtual' keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

<sub>UPDATE: This doesn't answer the question as currently asked, but I'll leave it here for anyone looking for a simple answer to the [original](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/8542864/1), non-descriptive question asked.</sub>

Comment: @Hooch this is not marked as correct because what is deemed "correct" doesn't merely depend on the question title. I imagine most people, myself and OP included, first deal with `virtual` properties through Entity Framework - even tho it's not explicit in OP's title. The accepted answer is so because it touches on the Entity Framework side of things, and how/why `virtual` properties are used in that context.

Comment: actually, as the title is not anymore actual, any of readers will search here for a pure "virtual" explanation.

Answer (score 28):

I understand the OPs frustration, this usage of virtual is not for the templated abstraction that the defacto virtual modifier is effective for.

If any are still struggling with this, I would offer my view point, as I try to keep the solutions simple and the jargon to a minimum:

Entity Framework in a simple piece does utilize lazy loading, which is the equivalent of prepping something for future execution.  That fits the 'virtual' modifier, but there is more to this.

In Entity Framework, using a virtual navigation property allows you to denote it as the equivalent of a nullable Foreign Key in SQL.  You do not HAVE to eagerly join every keyed table when performing a query, but when you need the information -- it becomes demand-driven.

I also mentioned nullable because many navigation properties are not relevant at first.  i.e. In a customer / Orders scenario, you do not have to wait until the moment an order is processed to create a customer.  You can, but if you had a multi-stage process to achieve this, you might find the need to **persist** the customer data for later completion or for deployment to future orders.  If all nav properties were implemented, you'd have to establish every Foreign Key and relational field on the save.  That really just sets the data back into memory, which defeats the role of persistence.

So while it may seem cryptic in the actual execution at run time, I have found the best rule of thumb to use would be: if you are outputting data (reading into a View Model or Serializable Model) and need values before references, do not use virtual; If your scope is collecting data that may be incomplete or a need to search and  not require every search parameter completed for a search, the code will make good use of reference, similar to using nullable value properties int? long?. 
Also, abstracting your business logic from your data collection until the need to inject it has many performance benefits, similar to instantiating an object and starting it at null.  Entity Framework uses a lot of reflection and dynamics, which can degrade performance, and the need to have a flexible model that can scale to demand is critical to managing performance.

To me, that always made more sense than using overloaded tech jargon like proxies, delegates, handlers and such.  Once you hit your third or fourth programming lang, it can get messy with these.

Answer (score 27):

In the context of EF, marking a property as **virtual** allows EF to use lazy loading to load it. For lazy loading to work EF has to create a proxy object that overrides your virtual properties with an implementation that loads the referenced entity when it is first accessed. If you don't mark the property as virtual then lazy loading won't work with it.

Comment: I like this concise answer.

Answer (score 19):

> It’s quite common to define navigational properties in a model to
>   be virtual. When a navigation property is defined as virtual, it can
>   take advantage of certain Entity Framework functionality. The
>   most common one is lazy loading.
>
> Lazy loading is a nice feature of many ORMs because it allows you
>   to dynamically access related data from a model. It will not unnecessarily
>   fetch the related data until it is actually accessed, thus
>   reducing the up-front querying of data from the database.

From book "ASP.NET MVC 5 with Bootstrap and Knockout.js"

Answer (score 1):

We can't talk about virtual members without referring to **polymorphism**. In fact, a function, property, indexer or event in a base class marked as virtual will **allow override from a derived class.**

By default, **members of a class are non-virtual** and cannot be marked as that if static, abstract, private, or override modifiers.

**Example**
Let's consider the **ToString()** method in **System.Object**. Because this method is a member of System.Object it's inherited in all classes and will provide the ToString() methods to all of them.

```
namespace VirtualMembersArticle
{
    public class Company
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Company company = new Company() { Name = "Microsoft" };
            Console.WriteLine($"{company.ToString()}");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }   
    }
}
```

The output of the previous code is:

```
VirtualMembersArticle.Company
```

Let's consider that we want to change the standard behavior of the ToString() methods inherited from System.Object in our Company class. To achieve this goal it's enough to use the override keyword to declare another implementation of that method.

```
public class Company
{
    ...
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Name: {this.Name}";
    }         
}
```

Now, when a virtual method is invoked, the run-time will check for an overriding member in its derived class and will call it if present. The output of our application will then be:

```
Name: Microsoft
```

In fact, if you check the System.Object class you will find that the method is marked as virtual.

```
namespace System
{
    [NullableContextAttribute(2)]
    public class Object
    {
        ....
        public virtual string? ToString();
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Entity Framework, using a virtual navigation property allows you to denote it as the equivalent of a nullable Foreign Key in SQL. You do not HAVE to eagerly join every keyed table when performing a query, but when you need the information -- it becomes demand-driven.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).