# Inheriting initialized fields

Tags: c#, inheritance

There is a behavior in C# I really do not understand:

```cs
class Animal {
        public string species = "animal";

        public void Introduce() {
            Console.WriteLine(species);
        }
    }


    class Cat: Animal {
        new public string species = "cat";

        // public void Introduce() {Console.WriteLine(species);}
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var cat = new Cat();
            cat.Introduce();
        }
    }
```

This piece of code, when executed, outputs `>>> animal`.
For me, since Cat inherits Animal, calling cat.Introduce should call Animal.Introduce "in the scope of the cat instance". *ie* I don't understand why the program picks the `species` field of Animal and not the one of Cat...

I know I could use workarounds, but I believe I'm missing some point about c# design, can someone explain this behavior?

Thanks

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9238795/virtual-properties

Comment: just remove "new"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I don't understand why the program picks the species field of Animal and not the one of Cat...

Because the `new` modifier hides the inherited `species` member... **but only inside the `Cat` instance**. You call the method on the base class, which only knows its own `species` member.

If you give your `Cat` class an `IntroduceCat()` method where you print its `species` and you call it, you'll see the "cat" string being printed.

If you want to override the member in a derived class, you must mark the member as `virtual` in the base class and `override` it in the derived class. But you can't do that to fields, so you'll have to make it a property.

But you probably just want to assign a different value, and you can do so in your constructor.