# The difference between = and => for a virtual member

Tags: c#, oop, virtual

Base class:

```cs
protected virtual List<string> Name { get; } = null;
```

Child class

```cs
protected override List<string> Name => new List<string>();// No error
```

if write equal operator:

```cs
protected override List<string> Name = new List<string>();
```

the compiler raise error:

```
"The modifier 'override' is not valid for this item"
```

=> is an anonymous function. In both cases we are assigning value to the `Name` member. Why is compiler giving error for `=` operator.

Comment: It sounds like you're just asking what an [expression bodied property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members) is.  You're getting a compiler error because an expression bodied property is *very different* from just declaring a field and assigning a value to it.

Comment: Maybe this can help [virtual property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9238902/13448436)

Comment: You are defining a class. With the lambda operator `=>` you are defining a function that will be used as the get accessor for the `Name` property. With the assignment operator `=`, you could initialize the property as `protected override List<string> Name { get; } = new List<string>();` (similar to the initialization in the base class).

Answer (score 2):

So you have a *property* in the base class:

```
// Read-only property which returns List<string> and 
// which is initialized with null 
protected virtual List<string> Name { get; } = null;
```

It's perfectly legal to *override* this property into a bit different one:

```
// Still read-only property which returns List<string> and
// which creates a new instance of List<string> on each call (note =>)
protected override List<string> Name => new List<string>();
```

But then you try to declare *field* instead of *property*, which is illegal:

```
// Name is a field (note abscence of "get")
// Compiler complains: it's impossible to override a field
protected override List<string> Name = new List<string>();
```

To correct your code, stick to *property*, add `{ get; }`:

```
// Read-only property which returns List<string> and 
// which is initialized with an instance of List<string>
protected override List<string> Name { get; } = new List<string>();
```