# Why Navigation Properties are virtual by default in EF

Tags: entity-framework, navigation-properties

I have following POCO class being used in EF 6.x.

**My question**: Why is the navigation property of 'Posts' under 'Blog' entity declared as virtual?

```
public class Blog 
{  
    public int BlogId { get; set; }  
    public string Name { get; set; }  
    public string Url { get; set; }  
    public string Tags { get; set; }  

    public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }  
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why use 'virtual' for class properties in Entity Framework model definitions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542864/why-use-virtual-for-class-properties-in-entity-framework-model-definitions)

Answer (score 102, accepted):

If you define your navigation property `virtual`, Entity Framework will at runtime create a new class (dynamic proxy) derived from your class and uses it instead of your original class. This new dynamically created class contains logic to load the navigation property when accessed for the first time.  This is referred to as "lazy loading".  It enables Entity Framework to avoid loading an entire tree of dependent objects which are not needed from the database.

In some circumstances, it is best to use "Eager Loading" instead, especially if you know that you will be interacting with related objects at some point.

Julie Lerman really is the authority on all things Entity Framework, and she explains this process very well in her MSDN Article [Demystifying Entity Framework Strategies: Loading Related Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh205756.aspx)

> Eager loading with Include is useful for scenarios where you know in advance that you want the related data for all of the core data being queried. But remember the two potential downsides. If you have too many Includes or navigation paths, the Entity Framework may generate a poorly performing query. And you should be careful about returning more related data than necessary thanks to the ease of coding with Include.
>
> Lazy loading very conveniently retrieves related data behind the scenes for you in response to code that simply makes mention of that related data. It, too, makes coding simpler, but you should be conscientious about how much interaction it’s causing with the database. You may cause 40 trips to the database when only one or two were necessary.

If you are developing a Web Application where every communication with the server is a new context anyway, Lazy Loading will just create unnecessary overhead to maintain the dynamic class for related objects that will never be loaded.  Many people will disable lazy loading in these scenarios.  Ultimately, it's still best to evaluate your SQL queries which EF has built and determine which options will perform best for the scenario you are developing under.

Comment: I don't quite agree with the point that in a web app lazy loading is not beneficial. Even though new context is created everytime in stateless applications, different repository calls may need different data out of the same context. For example, for the same Orders aggregate root, you may want to load Products collection this time but ShippingStatusHistory collection in another method. Having lazy loading on the context dbset level allows you to pick different data on different methods.