# Model property returning null, but value exists in db MVC5 EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am learning EF6 with MVC 5 following this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application). I understand this question may have been asked, however I am not sure what exactly I need to be looking for? I checked the db and data is in there? Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I have an issue where in my Model.Enrollments is null(this view takes a student model), however in the database it shows it has values in that table.

Model: **Student**

```
public int ID { get; set; }
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
```

**Course**

```
  public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Credits { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
```

**Enrollment**

```
public int ID { get; set; }
public decimal? Grade { get; set; }
public int StudentID { get; set; }
public int CourseID { get; set; }
public Student Student { get; set; }
public Course Course { get; set; }
```

**Exception:**

```
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_uycs14gs.dll but was not handled in user code
```

[image]
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Database:
[image]

Update- **Context**

```
  public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
       public DbSet<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
       protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
       {
           modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
```

Comment: Show your Context please.

Comment: Make Enrollments virtual and try

Comment: Looks like an exact duplicate of (the same tutorial, the same question) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15247614/understanding-code-first-virtual-properties

Comment: @Rex see updated question

Comment: where do i make it virtual? which class?@din

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your navigation properties as `virtual` if you want to be lazy loaded.

```
public class Student
{
   //...
   public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
  //...
  public virtual ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
}

public class Enrollment
{
  //...
  public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
  public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
}
```

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25715474/why-navigation-properties-are-virtual-by-default-in-ef) for a better explanation. When you are using POCO entity types, lazy loading is achieved by creating instances of derived proxy types and then overriding `virtual` properties to add the loading hook.

Comment: All your navigation properties

Comment: @Harry, check this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd468057(v=vs.100).aspx) to see all the requirements you need to follow

Comment: That seems to have done the trick thanks, I will read up more on this :)