# How to create a third table for Many to Many relationship in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two classes:
One is User

```
 public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public List<Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }
    }
```

Other is Subscription:

```
public class Subscription
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }
```

As you can see that User has a list of Subscriptions.
Now when using the entity framework code first approach I am getting a table for User which doesn't contain Subscriptions but a new column for User Id is being added to Subscription table. I was expecting to have a third table which contains two columns one with User ID and the other with subscription ID.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: That's a many-to-many association. Depends on the EF version which options you have. But it shouldn't be hard to find examples.

Comment: @GertArnold, I think you are right that its a many to many relationship, as one subscription can be associated with multiple users, but given that Subscription class doesn't contain a list of users, how would you approach this in EF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#many-to-many):

Many-to-many relationships without an entity class to represent the join table are not yet supported. However, you can represent a many-to-many relationship by including an entity class for the join table and mapping two separate one-to-many relationships.

So [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49592504/240564) is correct.

I just corrected code a little bit:

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Use> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Subscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserSubscription>()
            .HasKey(t => new { t.UserId, t.SubscriptionId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserSubscription>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.User)
            .WithMany(p => p.UserSubscription)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.UserId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserSubscription>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Subscription)
            .WithMany(t => t.UserSubscription)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.SubscriptionId);
    }
}

public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public List<UserSubscription> UserSubscriptions{ get; set; }
    }

public class Subscription
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public List<UserSubscription> UserSubscriptions{ get; set; }
    }

public class UserSubscription
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }

    public int SubscriptionId { get; set; }
    public Subscription Subscription { get; set; }
}
```

PS. You don't need use virtual in navigation property, because lazy loading [still not available in EF Core](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41881299/240564).

Answer (score 1):

Create a third middle table named: `UserSubscriptions` for example.

```
public class User
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<UserSubscription> Subscriptions { get; set; }
    }


public class Subscription
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}

  public class UserSubscription
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int SubscriptionID { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public virtual User { get; set; }
    public DateTime BeginDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

**Second Solution:**

Add reference for `Subscription` to `User` and name it `CurrentSubscription` for example.

```
public class User
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public int CurrentSubscriptionID { get; set; }
        public virtual Subscription Subscription { get; set; }
    }


public class Subscription
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what will happen when I add a new subscription to a current user? In which table will that entry go?

Comment: @Sameed I edited my solution because the first one wasn't a very good reliable one. check the new two solutions

Comment: In case of the first solution, isn't there a way EF can create a third table on its own without me specifying another class? For the second solution, it looks like if a new subscription is added for a user it will create a new entry in User table which I don't think is a good thing as all other columns data will be repeated?