# Entity Framework 6 Include retrieve data in null - relation one to one

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6

Department and store model. They are a one to one relationship. when I do the (Include) only some models it brings me the complete data.
The data is correctly in the database

```
 var orders = await _context.Order.Include(o => o.Departament)
                                  .Include(o => o.Store).ToArrayAsync();
```

Model Order

```
 public class Order
    {   [Key]
        public string Order_Id { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public string Number_Order { get; set; }  
        
        public int Qty { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime Imported { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime Modified { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime Exported { get; set; }

        public bool IsActive { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Departament")]
        public string DepartmentId { get; set; }
        
        [ForeignKey("Store")]
        public string StoreId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
       
        public Departament Departament { get; set; }

        public Store  Store { get; set; }
    }
```

.

I just need to solve that problem of getting the data correctly.

Comment: The relationship between Order->Department and Order->Store is not One-to-One, it is Many-to-One. (Many orders could refer to the same Department) If you are hard-wiring any configuration in OnModelCreating for instance to use a HasOne/WithOne or such what you may be encountering conflicting issues where it is trying to match on the two table's PKs (which is the default behavior for One-to-One relationships) rather than the FKs. The other thing to verify is that at runtime the DbContext is actually pointing at the same database instance that your are checking against.

Answer (score -1):

1. what do u mean one to one!!! i think your design is one to many.
   as Steve Py said in his comment ## The relationship between Order->Department and Order->Store is not One-to-One, it is Many-to-One. (Many orders could refer to the same Department) ##
2. use virtual keyword for navigation properties.
   accroding to https://stackoverflow.com/a/41881299/18399373
   you can use virtual keyword to load related data in lazy way
3. use explicit loading and check it.
   **Entity Framework supports three ways to load related data - eager loading, lazy loading and explicit loading**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks  i think was one to one. is one to many. Thanks Thanks.