# Why do you need explicitly disable Lazy loading in EF?

Tags: entity-framework

based on documentation, if you apply **virtual keyword** to navigation property, you **Enable Lazy loading**.

In another documentation, it says, to **disable lazy loading** you need to apply this code

> context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

Logically, why not just **NOT** apply **virtual** keyword in the first place?

I don't understand why over complicate things?

Thanks.

Comment: Excluding VIRTUAL turns lazy loading off for that item. `context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;` turns it off for the entire context. Not really that complicated:  http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/lazyloading-in-entity-framework.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The reason the virtual keyword was applied to navigation properties was to limit the entire dependency tree from being loading when making a call into the database by default.  Check out these other SO questions/answers.

[Why Navigation Properties are virtual by default in EF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25715474/why-navigation-properties-are-virtual-by-default-in-ef)

[Why use 'virtual' for class properties in Entity Framework model definitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542864/why-use-virtual-for-class-properties-in-entity-framework-model-definitions)