# Entity Framework returns null for Include properties

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework

I got 3 entities(tables) that have many to many connections:

```
public class AccUserRole
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public List<AccAdGroup> Groups { get; set; }
    public List<AccScreen> Screens { get; set; }
}

public class AccAdGroup
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string AdIdent { get; set; }
    public List<AccUserRole> Roles { get; set; }
}



public class AccScreen
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string ScreenIdent { get; set; }
    public List<AccUserRole> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

I wanted to get all Roles(including their screens and groups) that has at least one of specified list of groups(the groups of the current user). So I used this query:

```
List<AccUserRole> userRoles = (from ur in db.AccUserRoles.Include("Groups").Include("Screens")
                               from g in ur.Groups
                               where user.Groups.Contains(g.AdIdent)
                               select ur).ToList();
```

It gets the right roles, but the `Groups` and `Screens` properties are null. Looks like EF has a problem with using `Include` and second `from`.
Any help on how to include the properties or rewrite the query will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the virtual key word to your class properties like so:

```
public class AccUserRole
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public virtual List<AccAdGroup> Groups { get; set; }
    public virtual List<AccScreen> Screens { get; set; }
}

public class AccAdGroup
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string AdIdent { get; set; }
    public virtual List<AccUserRole> Roles { get; set; }
}



public class AccScreen
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string ScreenIdent { get; set; }
    public virtual List<AccUserRole> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why does this solve the problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542864/why-use-virtual-for-class-properties-in-entity-framework-model-definitions

See this link!

Answer (score 4):

**Eager Loading**

The reason for this is that you have specified only one level of include, while your query is asking for something on the second level.

Your include lets you ask for `ur.Groups` and `ur.Screens`.
The next level is `from g in ur.Groups`, and you haven't included that level. (This is probably unexpected for you, since you already have asked for all `AccUserRoles` in the first part of the query.)

To make your query run, you could add another `.include` at the start, going two levels deep:

```
from ur in db.AccUserRoles
             .Include("Groups")
             .Include("Groups.Roles")
             .Include("Screens")
```

If you need to go yet another level, you'd just add yet another include:

```
from ur in db.AccUserRoles
             .Include("Groups")
             .Include("Groups.Roles")
             .Include("Groups.Roles.Groups")
             .Include("Screens")
```

...etc.

This might become cumbersome if you have a whole lot of levels to nest, so an alternative would be to use *Lazy Loading* instead, as Praval 'Shaun' Tirubeni suggests, by adding the `virtual` keyword to the collections in your entities.

Answer (score 3):

Move the include before `ToList()`.

```
select ur).Include("Groups").Include("Screens").ToList();
```

The subselect can remove the `Include` effect.

If you are doing eager loading, the `virtual` keyword is not needed.
By adding `virtual`, you are using lazy loading, not eager loading.