# MVC EF: Adding one to many component by ID

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys, parent-child

I am working with two classes Company and Visitor that have a one-to-many relationship.

```
public class Company
{
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Visitor> Visitors { get; set; }
}

public class Visitor
{
    public int VisitorID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public bool SendNewsletter { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

I have a page where a Visitor can fill out information about themselves. The idea is that if a Company is not in the db, it will get added to the list. If the CompanyName the Visitor enters matches a name in the db, the Company is associated with the Visitor, rounding out its required info, which is then added to its own db.

```
 var companyExists = db.Companies.Any(c => c.CompanyName == visitor.Company.CompanyName);
 if(companyExists)
 {
      var existingCompany = db.Companies.SingleOrDefault(c => c.CompanyName == visitor.Company.CompanyName);
      visitor.CompanyID = existingCompany.CompanyID;
      visitor.Company = existingCompany;
 }

 db.Visitors.Add(visitor);
 db.SaveChanges();
```

This code works but it seems redundant. I am associating the Visitor's CompanyID with the existing Company and then doing the same for the Company. Everything I read suggests that updating the Visitor's CompanyID should be sufficient but if I don't map the existingCompany to the Visitor's Company parameter, a second CompanyID is created. I feel like I'm missing some crucial point and am hoping someone here can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You don not need set `visitor.Company`. You can get `Company` information by `CompanyID` and you can use `Where` and `FirstOrDefault` to avoid redundant like this:

```
var companyExists = db.Companies.Where(c => c.CompanyName == visitor.Company.CompanyName).FirstOrDefault();
if (companyExists)
{
   visitor.CompanyID = companyExists.CompanyID;
   // visitor.Company = companyExists;
}
```

Notice that `public virtual Company Company { get; set; }` allows the Entity Framework to create a proxy around the virtual property so that the property can support lazy loading and more efficient change tracking. Please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542864/why-use-virtual-for-class-properties-in-entity-framework-model-definitions) for more information about `virtual` property in EF.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Ali. I tried what you suggested but the program is still creating a new ID for Visitor.Company.CompanyID which does not match with Visitor.CompanyID. Is there a simpler way to link the two? I thought it was lazy loading so I enabled it and got no change.

Comment: @Yusif_Nurizade Are you adding `visitor` and `Company` in a block of code?

Comment: Ali Soltani could you please clarify what you mean? What block of code? I have the existing code at the top. If the Company exists, I do not add it, just associate the ID per your suggestion but that still creates a new Company with a different ID.

Comment: @Yusif_Nurizade I've already encountered this problem. I think before `if (companyExists)` you filled `visitor.Company`. Add `visitor.Company = null` after `visitor.CompanyID = companyExists.CompanyID;` and check it again.

Comment: @Ani Soltani thank you for the suggestion but this is essentially the same as having visitor.Company = existingCompany; Is there a cleaner way to accomplish the task? I was hoping to set the ID and not create a new one in the partially written company.