# Object property is null after taking data from DB. Entity Framework

Tags: database, entity-framework, linq, null

I have a `DBContext` that is initializing through `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` class.
In the `Seed` method I have this code:

```
            base.Seed(context);
            var c1 = new Company { Name = "Samsung"};
            var c2 = new Company { Name = "Microsoft"};
            context.Companies.AddRange(new List<Company>{c1,c2 });
            var phones = new List<Phone>
            {
                new Phone("Samsung Galaxy S5", 20000, c1),
                new Phone("Nokia S1243", 200000, c1),
                new Phone("Nokia 930", 10000, c2),
                new Phone("Nokia 890", 8900, c2)

            };
            context.Phones.AddRange(phones);

            context.SaveChanges();
```

And if iterate through `phones` now, I see that `phone.Company` is not `null`.
But when I do this in any other piece of code, `phone.Company` IS `null`.
What do I do wrong?
A simple piece of code with null `phone.Company`:

```
using (var db = new MyDataModel())
        {
            var phonesList = db.Phones.ToList();
            foreach (var p in phones)
            {
                System.Console.WriteLine($"Name: {p.Name} 
                Company: {p.Company}"); // Company is null.
            }
        }
```

I can access `Company` using `Join` with Companies on `phone.companyId`, so `Companies` table exists in DB.

My `DataModel` class:

```
public class MyDataModel : DbContext
{
    public MyDataModel()
        : base("name=MyDataModel")
    {
    }

    static MyDataModel()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MyContextInializer());
    }

    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Phone> Phones { get; set; }
}
```

My `Phone` class:

```
namespace DataContext
{


public class Phone
    {
        public Phone()
        {

        }
        public Phone(string name, int price, Company company)
        {
            Name = name;
            Price = price;
            Company = company;
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Price { get; set; }

        public int CompanyId { get; set; }

        public Company Company { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to automagically load the companies when you load a phone, you need to add the `virtual` keyword before the Company property.

```
public class Phone { 

    public Phone() {

    }
    public Phone(string name, int price, Company company)
    {
        Name = name;
        Price = price;
        Company = company;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Price { get; set; }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

}
```

This tells entity framework to automatically load the linked company whenever you retrieve a phone from the database.

Alternatively you can use eager loading when performing a query on phones.

```
var phones = MyDataModel.Phones.Include(x => x.Company).ToList();
```

Comment: that means that all the companies will be load? Even if I need only one Phone?

Comment: No it gets only the Company linked to the requested phone(s)

Comment: Immorality, and the same occurs if I use that "virtual" approach, right?

Comment: Yes, the virtual approach will always include the Company when you retrieve a phone

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the cool answer from Immorality, I'll place here these links:

1. [Virtual properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8542864/why-use-virtual-for-class-properties-in-entity-framework-model-definitions)
2. [MSDN - Loading related data strategies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh205756.aspx)