# SQL Server views vs LINQ to entities queries with EF Code First

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, ef-code-first, sql-view

Question is related only to Entity Framework 5 code-first. What is the better option (performance and scalability):

1. Create SQL Server views, treat them as `DbSets` in your `DbContext`.
2. Create custom classes that represent view models, use Linq to Entities to project Entity model to View model before query is executed.

Answer (score 0):

well it depend on how big is your query if its huge and require a lot of precessing i suggest that you create a view this way all the heavy work will be on the SQL Server and your application would be much faster when processing.

I recommend also using virtual classes instead creating a new one because you will have all the entity framework functionality available. check this link

[What effect(s) can the virtual keyword have in Entity Framework 4.1 POCO Code First?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597760/what-effects-can-the-virtual-keyword-have-in-entity-framework-4-1-poco-code-fi)

Hope this help