# Entity Framework SaveChanges two behaviours depending on how I add to DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have overridden my db.SaveChanges() so I can call my FluentValidation validators before it actually attempts to save it.

I have a validator for each entity marked with IValidatableEntity and if the entity matches it will call it and pass the objectStateEntry in.

```
public virtual IEnumerable<string> SaveChanges(User user)
{
     List<string> validationErrors = new List<string>();
     if (this.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled)
     {
         foreach (var entry in ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager
              .GetObjectStateEntries(System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added | System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted | System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified | System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged)
              .Where(entry => (entry.Entity is IValidatableEntity)))
              {
                  validationErrors.AddRange(((IValidatableEntity)entry.Entity).Validate(entry));
              }
         }

    if (!validationErrors.Any())
    { .....
```

The problem I have is that I get two different behaviours depending on how I add the object to the dbContext. I Guess because it only marks the aggregate root as being modified and only gives it an entry?

```
// Example A - Calls the Organisation Validator Only
 organisation.Client.Add(client); 

// Example B - Calls the Client Validator - which is correct
db.Client.Add(client);
```

Is there anyway to get EF automatically detect child properties have changed (Add / Modified) and call them? It kind of breaks my validation model if it doesn't, I was banking on updating the aggregate root and having EF call the necessary child validations as they should have unique entries.

Do I have to chain validators inside my Fluent Validations to catch these? I Didn't want a case of where my fluent Validator will have to check potentially hundreds of child entities. (some contain db lookups etc).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to call `DetectChanges` at the beginning of your overridden `SaveChanges` method (it must be **before** you call `GetObjectStateEntries`):

```
this.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
```

The difference between the two lines to add a `Client` is that `organisation.Client.Add(client)` does not call any EF code directly (it's just adding an item to a collection in a POCO) while `db.Client.Add(client)` does and the `DbSet<T>.Add` method will call change detection automatically to update the entity states.

In the first case if you don't call any EF method before `SaveChanges` the `base.SaveChanges` will detect the changes as the very last place to ensure that all entity states are correct and all changes are saved. But `base.SaveChanges` is too late for the code in your overridden `SaveChanges` because it is **after** your evaluation of `GetObjectStateEntries`. At that point the entity state of the added `client` could still be `Detached` (i.e. not existing in the state manager) instead of `Added`. In order to fix this you have to call `DetectChanges` manually early enough to retrieve the final entity states in `GetObjectStateEntries`.

Comment: Brilliant thanks slauma that all makes sense. You both gave great answers I cant tell who posted first. But as ken mentioned your post ill assume you did first.

Comment: @PeterLea: You can always see an exact timestamp when you hover with your mouse over that "answered *x hours ago*" text below the answers.

Answer (score 1):

I assume `organisation` is a simple POCO, so the following code:

```
organisation.Client.Add(client);
```

just adds another POCO in an `ICollection` of POCOs. EF has no way to detect you are adding an entity to the context.

In the other hand, the following code:

```
db.Client.Add(client);
```

adds a POCO directly in an implementation of `ICollection` (`DbCollectionEntry`) that is related to Entity Framework and is in charge of what's called **change tracking** (among other things). This is possible thanks to dynamic proxy types generated at runtime (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14321968/870604).

So you'll have to detect changes manually (see @Slauma answer). Another option would be to use a proxy object instead of your `organisation` POCO. This would be possible by calling:

```
var newOrganisation = dbContext.Set<Organisation>().Create();
```

The above code of course works for a new `organisation` instance.

Comment: Thanks ken. Brilliant answer I wish I could share the bounty. Sorry if I got it wrong and you answered first!