# How to specify what level of SQL hierarchy to return?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Using ASP.NET 4.5 and EF 6, I've put together a multilevel data model that looks like this:

**Organization**, which has an ICollection of:

_____**Workspaces**, which has an ICollection of:

__________**Projects**, which has an ICollection of:

_______________**Cards**

When I ask the database for a list of organizations using the following code, I get a giant multilevel nested response all the objects in the database.

```
var orgs = await (from o in db.Organizations select o).ToListAsync();
```

How do I specify that I just want the top level to be returned? (or any other specific depth of search?)

I'm sure this is easy, but I'm new to SQL C# world and don't know the proper language to find useful Google or SO answers...

---

Update: kienct89 gets the win!

"Lazy Loading" is the right term, and here's [some good info about it](http://www.ryadel.com/en/enable-or-disable-lazyloading-in-entity-framework/).

Comment: can you most more details about your model?  it's possible you need to address lady loading.  Look at lazy loading in [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/reading-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `Eager loading` vs `Lazy loading` in `entity framework`

**Lazy Loading**: data will be loaded **automatically** when you execute the query (serialize the object, cast to enumerable, list, etc)

**Eager Loading**: data will be loaded manually **ONLY IF you want to** (by using `Include()` function)

If you want to turn off `Lazy Loading` you can use the block code below

```
Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; // in the db context class
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not wish to globally disable lazy loading (which Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled does), you can target specific properties by [omitting the virtual key word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14321097/c-sharp-ef-code-first-virtual-keyword-what-does-it-do) in the declaration.

Comment: Also a good tidbit! (that must be why you asked about what the models looked like...)