# Entity Framework 4 Code First Many-to-Many relationship slow

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, code-first

I have a `Category` object and a `Product` object.  They have a many-to-many relationship, so the `CategoryProduct` table gets created when the database gets initialized. In the `OnModelCreating` method I have the following code to map the relationship

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
    .HasMany( c => c.Products )
    .WithMany( i => i.Categories )
    .Map( t => t.MapLeftKey( "CategoryId" )
    .MapRightKey( "ProductId" )
    .ToTable( "CategoryProducts" ));
```

The `CategoryProducts` table gets loaded correctly and everything's good. But when I am actually debugging the site, it takes an extremely long time to navigate to a category.  For example, there is an 'Accessories' category that has over 1400 products.  The code will grab everything for the category selected, but it will lazy load the products when it needs them.  When it is lazy loading the products is when it takes the long time ( obviously ).  I need to know how I can speed this up.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks a lot

EDIT: Here are the `Category` and `Product` classes

```
public class Category : WebPage
    {
        private int _count = -1;
        public bool IsFeatured { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Category> Children { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Product> Products { get; set; }    
        public virtual List<Discount> Discounts { get; set; }
}

public class Product : WebPage
    {
        public string Sku { get; set; }
        public string Details { get; set; }
        public string AdditionalDetails { get; set; }    

        public virtual List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public virtual Brand Brand { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT: Code doing the query

```
public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
            Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
            Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
            string includeProperties = "", int? limit = null)
        {
            IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

            if (filter != null)
            {
                query = query.Where(filter);
            }

            foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
                (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
            {
                query = query.Include(includeProperty);
            }

            if (limit != null && limit.HasValue && limit.GetValueOrDefault() > 0)
            {
                query = query.Take(limit.Value);
            }

            if (orderBy != null)
            {
                return orderBy(query).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                return query;
            }
        }
```

Comment: The issue is not in here, it is in where you use `CategoryProducts`, you should show more code

Comment: Can't tell much without seeing code, but if you are just pulling down data for read only purposes, you can apply `.AsNoTracking()` to your reads to speed things up a bit

Comment: What code would you like to see? I'll put the `Category` and `Product` classes up

Comment: I think the "Include method" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx might be what you are looking for, by using include you are basically telling entity-framework to retrieve the desired fields in the first query execution and not lazy-load them

Comment: @BahadorIzadpanah wouldn't that still make the query slow?

Comment: It depends on your use-case, generally if those properties are frequently accessed it's a good idea to include them otherwise there will be some database access for each one, would you check to see if that helps in your case? the number of records you mentioned is not that much IMHO.exactly how much time do you mean by "long time"? are you checking that time in the debugger watch? cause if that's the case it might be normal.

Comment: Ok I will test it out with the 'Include'. With that, should I remove the virtual tag from the List<product> in the category class?

Comment: @BahadorIzadpanah And to answer your questions, 'long time' i mean like 2 minutes+.

Comment: @AarronH I've just found out that apparently using the virtual keyword will enable lazy loading by default so removing it might have the same effect but I'm not sure about that sorry, more info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597760/what-effects-can-the-virtual-keyword-have-in-entity-framework-4-1-poco-code-fi)

Comment: You might also be able to use .skip() and .take()  methods to only retrieve as much items as needed back. I also recommend including the lines of code in which you are querying against the EF in the question.

Comment: @BahadorIzadpanah if you do so you will not disable but make impossible lazy loading. To disable lazy loading use `someContext.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;`

Comment: @BahadorIzadpanah I will edit the question to show the code that is doing the querying.  Its just the normal Get method.

Comment: @tschmit007 I understand that by "doing so"  you mean removing the virtual keyword right? thanks for the tip

Comment: @BahadorIzadpanah absolutely :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine you `Get<Category>(x => x.SomeName == "abcdef")` and the iterate on Products.

Can't you `Get<Product>(x => x.Categories.Where(y => y.SomeName == "abcdef").Count() > 0)` ?

Comment: This is pretty much what I did.. Thanks