# How to express LINQ to Entities query without 'Only primitive types' error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, exception, linq-to-entities

I have a Game model that have many Organizer models attached to it. Here are my models:

```
public class Organizer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Game> Games {get; set; }
}

public class Game
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public List<Organizer> Organizers { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to grab all the Games that contain a specific Organizer. For instance, I might have some data like this:

```
Game
ID    Name
--    ----
1     Soccer
2     Baseball

Organizer
ID    Name
--    ----
1     John
2     Barry

GameOrganizer
GameID    OrganizerID
------    -----------
1         1
2         1
```

And here's the code I try to use:

```
Organizer thisOrganizer = db.Organizers.Single(o => o.ID == 1);

var gamesQuery = db.Games
    .Where(game => game.Organizers.Contains(thisOrganizer))
    .Select(g => new { ID = g.ID, Name = g.Name });
```

This gives me an error:

> Only primitive types are supported in this context.

I understand what it means, but I can't figure out how to express it in a different way. The closest I've come is:

```
var gamesQuery = db.Games
    .Where(game => game.Organizers
        .Any(gO => gO.ID == 1));
```

but that just returns nothing. I've looked everywhere but everything deals with string arrays that are already known in advance.

So, how can I express this without model objects?

Comment: Isn´t there a `Games` property on your Organizer class? Is this code-first? Can you post the 2 classes?

Comment: @Jobo There is a Games property on Organizer. This is code-first. I'll put up the classes.

Comment: Then abatishchev´s answer should be the way to go i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare also Games as (navigation) property of Organizer, then it will be just:

```
db.Organizers.Single(o => o.ID == 1).Games;
```

Comment: Oh my goodness, I don't know why I didn't think about doing it that way. This makes sense.

After making the changes it works! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In your `Organizer` class your Games property should look like this:

```
public virtual ICollection<Game> Games { get; set; }
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597760/what-effects-can-the-virtual-keyword-have-in-entity-framework-4-1-poco-code-fi) why.

Then you should be able to access all Games like abatishchev wrote in his answer:

```
Organizer thisOrganizer = db.Organizers.Single(o => o.ID == 1);
var games = thisOrganizer.Games;
```