# Cant view Index Action for displaying data in MVC

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

My insert in two tables is a success but I am getting error on Index action to display the data.

Model and View Models.

View Models

```
public class VMUsers
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
}
```

Models

```
[Table("tblUsers")]
public class Users
{   
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

[Table("tblUserDetails")]
public class UserDetails
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }

    public int UserID { get; set; }
}
```

DBSet

```
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<MVCLearning.Models.VMUsers> Combination { get; set; }
```

Index Action

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Combination.ToList());
        
    }
```

Getting exception

> An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.

Cant understand what is this inner excepton.

It breaks so the debug part to see the error also breaks it doesn't goes to the View for debugging.

Comment: `VMUsers` is a view model, not a data model. It should not have any relation to EF.

Comment: Also, Are you sure your entity model definition is correct ? Has enough foreign key relation shipis between the tables ?

Comment: As if now was praticing to add data in two tables so kept it simple and no PK and FK was kept but in real time PK and FK will be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you should do is create navigation properties between your entities, but first I think you are trying to create an one to one relationship between `User` and `UserDetail`. If that is the case, the PK of the dependent entity (in this case `UserDetail`) also should be FK of your relationship. Your model would be this way:

```
[Table("tblUsers")]
public class Users
{   
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual UserDetail Detail { get; set; }
}

[Table("tblUserDetails")]
public class UserDetails
{
    [Key,ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Now the `DBSet<TEntity>` properties in your context must be defined using your entity types:

```
public DbSet<MVCLearning.Models.User> Users { get; set; }
public DbSet<MVCLearning.Models.UserDetail> UserDetails { get; set; }
```

Now in your controller you can declare a query like this projecting the result in your VM class:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(db.Users.Select(u=>new VMUsers{ Id=u.Id,
                                                FullName=u.FullName,
                                                LastName=u.LastName,
                                                Address2=u.Detail.Address1,
                                                Address1=u.Detail.Address2}));

}
```

Comment: Why public virtual UserDetail Detail { get; set; } and                             public virtual User User { get; set; }  Have seen lot of developers doing this with virtual key word but didn't understood the importance of it.

Comment: That is a requirement for lazy loading. Check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597760/what-effects-can-the-virtual-keyword-have-in-entity-framework-4-1-poco-code-fi), and in this [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd468057(v=vs.110).aspx) page explains more in details all the requirements that you need to meet.

Comment: Learned alot from your reply.