# Join LINQ tables based on model definition

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, join

I want to join tables using linq, based on the definition of the model. Example of what I want:

**from department in User.departments...**

My classes are:

**USER CLASS:**

```
public class User
{
    public User() {
        Departments = new List<Department>();
    }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Department> Departments { get; set; }
}
```

**DEPARTMENT CLASS:**

```
public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

I'm creating inside the user class this:

```
public bool hasDepartment(int DepartmentId, int UserId)
{
    var test = from department in User.departments
    //...
}
```

But I'm having this message: ***'User' does not contain a definition for 'departments'.***

I'm creating a ASP.NET MVC application. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: why `virtual` here?

Comment: LINQ is correct, the User object does not have a definition for `departments`. It does, however, have one for `Departments` (notice the casing). I also agree with @Div, why virtual properties? Are you going to be overloading these somewhere else in some other subclasses?

Comment: @Div most likely for lazy loading: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5599270/3330348

Comment: It's also not clear is `User` a class name or some collection reference in `hasDepartment` method. If it's the former, you should use `this` instead.

Comment: You're right. I had to use this. Thats it

Comment: @PiotrWolkowski, hmm..right hope so.

Comment: I've read the post about virtual and non virtual and I still don't get it. :/

Comment: @Richasantos I don't think it was directly related to your problem. I posted that as an answer to a question asked by Div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> User' does not contain a definition for 'departments'

Issue exist since `Departments` is not a static collection inside `User class`, so you need an object of `User class` to access the `Departments ICollection` property

Since in the `User class`, modify the access as follows:

`var test = from department in Departments` Or

```
`var test = from department in this.Departments`
```

Idea is same, to have `object` based access instead of `static` access

Answer (score 1):

If the spelling of your message is exact then the reason for the error must be `departments` with lower `d`. Your 'Departments' property in the class definition is capital `D`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public bool hasDepartment(int DepartmentId, int UserId)
{
    var test = from department in Departments
    ...
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.