# Entity framework code first, custom foreign key name for inheritance

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, ef-code-first, foreign-keys

I have a class named MyEntity

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(300)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And an inherited class HubEntity

```
public class HubEntity : Entity
{
  [Key]
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
  public int EntityId { get; set; }

  [Required]
  [StringLength(300)]
  public string RootName { get; set; }
}
```

This is based on existing tables in the database. There is one table for each class. Thus the `EntityId` field in the `HubEntity` table refers to the `Id` field in the `Entity` table.

[image: DB Model]

In order to avoid demolishing the existing database, I run my code on a empty database and let the EF create the tables:

[image: Actual DB model]

My concern is that the HubEntity table is built with both the Id and EntityId fields, the ID field being designed as the foreign key to the Entity table. I don't know how to get the EntityId field to be used as the foreign key.

I tried to tag it `[ForeignKey("Entity")]`, but then I get an exception: the program looks for an Entity property in HubEntity that points to an Entity, which is not what I want because it's heritage.

I first created the application using DB first and here is what the model was looking like:
[image: DB Firts model]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Cedric

Comment: Your mistaking inheritance and foreign key concept, they are not the same, plus, this is not code first : these are partial classes, so it's DB first...

Comment: well... it looks like db first, and partial classes does not represent the table, it's just an ADD up, it's your model you need to change

Comment: There is no mistaking : I created the DB first and built a first version of my app upon it, using DB first. In this version, the model implemented inheritance of Entity -> HubEntity based on the two tables. For some reasons, I decided to rebuild the app from scratch using code first, which I'm less familiar with. I want to achieve inheritance Table Per Type, my only concern being this foreign key. I don't mix the foreign key concept on the db side and the inheritance on the code side, but I know that with TPT, the inheritance in the code is materialized by a foreign key in the table.

Comment: The partial classes come from the code generated by the reverse engineering made by visual studio when implementing code-first on existing db.

Comment: you can't build a db first aproach only with partial classes, what is your model looking like ? Like this guy : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40937111/data-displaying-null-types/40938410?noredirect=1#comment69099399_40938410  look at his db first model...

Comment: I am building a code first approach with reverse engineering. I edited my question to add models and removed _partial_ from the classes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130112/discussion-between-cedric-bourgeois-and-antoine-pelletier).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, got it.

The class MyEntity is ok.

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(300)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The inherited class HubEntity must not contain the EntityId field:

```
public class HubEntity : Entity
{
  [Required]
  [StringLength(300)]
  public string RootName { get; set; }
}
```

Now, in the `MyModel.cs`, in `OnModelCreating`, add the following clause:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<HubEntity>()
    .Property(e => e.Id)
    .HasColumnName("EntityId");
```

And the foreign key will be generated with the desired name. :)