# C# Entity Framework ObjectContext instance has been disposed

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I get the following error when I want to iterate over a List

```
The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.
```

I open the Form with the following code

```
        private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            int id = int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            Aufenthalt a;
            using (var db = new GastContext())
            {
                a = db.Aufenthalte.First(x => x.AufenthaltID == id);
            }

            Aufenthaltsform frm = new Aufenthaltsform(currentGast, a);
            frm.ShowDialog();
        }
```

And this is the constructor of my form and here my Application throws the above error

```
    public Aufenthaltsform(Gast g, Aufenthalt a)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MessageBox.Show(a.Mitreisende.Count.ToString());
    }
```

That's the Aufenthalt-Object

```
    public class Aufenthalt
    {
        public int AufenthaltID { get; set; }
        public DateTime Anreisedatum { get; set; }
        public DateTime Abreisedatum { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Mitreisender> Mitreisende { get; set; }

        public virtual Gast Gast { get; set; }

        public Aufenthalt()
        {
            Mitreisende = new List<Mitreisender>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40729137/why-are-foreign-keys-in-ef-code-first-marked-as-virtual/40729675#40729675 take a look at this to have a bit of theoric on why this happens

Answer (score 2):

Your `Aufenthalt` has two navigation properties - `Mitreisende` and `Gast`. Which require non-disposed `DbContext` when you are using lazy-loading. That's why you have error when try read those properties after disposing context via `using` statement:

```
Aufenthalt a;
using (var db = new GastContext())
{
    a = db.Aufenthalte.First(x => x.AufenthaltID == id);
}

// db is disposed here
Aufenthaltsform frm = new Aufenthaltsform(currentGast, a);
```

You can:

- remove `using` statement to keep context alive
- use eager loading instead of lazy loading
- move form creation and displaing inside `using` statement
- get Mitreisende count and pass number into form instead of passing root object and using navigation property later

First option - `DbContext` is a lightweight object, it's ok not to dispose it.

```
var db = new GastContext();
Aufenthalt a = db.Aufenthalte.First(x => x.AufenthaltID == id);
Aufenthaltsform frm = new Aufenthaltsform(currentGast, a);
```

Second option - not very good option, because you only need count of related entities. Why loading them all into memory? But you can

```
Aufenthalt a;
using (var db = new GastContext())
{
    a = db.Aufenthalte.Include(x => x.Mitreisende).First(x => x.AufenthaltID == id);
}

Aufenthaltsform frm = new Aufenthaltsform(currentGast, a);
```

Third option is obvious

```
using (var db = new GastContext())
{
    Aufenthalt a = db.Aufenthalte.First(x => x.AufenthaltID == id);
    Aufenthaltsform frm = new Aufenthaltsform(currentGast, a);
    frm.ShowDialog();
}
```

And best option is not passing to form data which are not required. It needs only count of Mitreisende, not whole collection. So change your form to

```
public Aufenthaltsform(Gast g, int mitreisendeCount)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MessageBox.Show(mitreisendeCount.ToString());
}
```

And call it this way

```
int mitreisendeCount;
using (var db = new GastContext())
{
    mitreisendeCount = db.Aufenthalte.First(x => x.AufenthaltID == id).Mitreisende.Count;
}

Aufenthaltsform frm = new Aufenthaltsform(currentGast, mitreisendeCount );
```

Comment: Or use .Include

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure that the query is executed before the context is disposed:

```
a = db.Aufenthalte.First(x => x.AufenthaltID == id);
// place this within the disposable context (using)
int count = a.Mitreisende.Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

The object `a` itself is filled after loading, but it has a navigation property `Mitreisende` that has not been filled yet at that moment (and Entity Framework also remembers that it has not done so yet).

The moment you call `a.Mitreisende.Count`, Entity Framework tries to fill the Mitreisende property, but it can not do so because the `using` statement caused the DbContext to be disposed, leading to the error.

There are multiple fixes:

1) Don't dispose the DbContext, simply by removing the `using` block. .NET will remove it by itself a little later, which in many cases will not hurt.

2) Dispose the DbContext by yourself, but do it a little later by putting the next 2 lines inside the block, instead of after it.

3) Make sure that Entity Framework loads the `Mitreisende` as soon as possible instead of delaying it, using an `.Include` statement:

```
a = db.Aufenthalte.Include(x => x.Mitreisende).First(x => x.AufenthaltID == id);
```