# I am facing this issue , when i run a web api in swagger....how I solve this error?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

[Null Exception Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vs8nx.png)

[Designation Repository class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fgdt.png)

Comment: Don't put errors and code into images. Please edit your question, so we can read the code (and perhaps copy it to run it locally).

Comment: Maybe you can try to check if the database exists,you can refer to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44666602/ef6-nullreferenceexception-with-any-tolist).

Answer (score 0):

Judging based on limited information provided.
Simply put it means that you are trying to use something that doesn't exist.
Essentially this [image] is returning a `null` value.

Without better question can't provide further help