# Entity Framework Include doesn't work without virtual

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, lazy-loading

I have two tables(`Teacher` and `Course`) in my database and EF mapping:

```
public partial class Teacher
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

And I load a teacher like this:

```
public Teacher GetTeacher(long id)
{
    using(var entities = new MyEntities())
    {
        var teacher = entities.Teachers.Where(t => t.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
        return teacher;
    }
}
```

Now sometimes I want to load Courses list for my Teacher. So I changed implementation like this:

```
public Teacher GetTeacher(long id, bool loadCourses)
{
    using(var entities = new MyEntities())
    {
        var teacherQuery = entities.Teachers.Where(t => t.Id == id);
        if(loadCourses)
        {
            teacherQuery.Include(t => t.Courses);
        }

        return teacherQuery.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

And this worked fine. But after that, I decided to turn off LazyLoading for Courses property since I've decided to control this manually by `loadCourses` field.

So I've just removed `virtual` from Courses collection:

```
public ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
```

This did help to turn off LazyLoading but `Include` stopped working and my `Courses` collection never loads.

So the question is: is it possible to do eager loading for `Courses` collection with LazyLoading disabled?

P.S. I don't actually use entity objects in my application but convert them to my Domain objects. So that's why I decided to use `bool loadCourses` field instead of actually using LazyLoading.

Also, I'd like to have one SELECT query(with JOIN, of course) sent to the database instead of two separate SELECTs.

Comment: Did you try setting context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled to false?

Comment: No, I didn't, because I have other tables in `MyEntities`. And I don't want to affect them.

Comment: Also, really consider if you need this - there is a reason why lazy loading is enabled by default and using virtual keyword allows EF to do efficient change tracking.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius Any links about `virtual` and change tracking would be appreciated.

Comment: @steavy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597760/what-effects-can-the-virtual-keyword-have-in-entity-framework-4-1-poco-code-fi, also kinda old, but I think still relevant - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adonet/2009/05/28/poco-in-the-entity-framework-4-part-2-complex-types-deferred-loading-and-explicit-loading/

Comment: Lazy loading has nothing to do with eager loading, so yes, it is entirely possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortly after asking the question, I found an answer which is dead simple: there is a bug under `if(loadCourses)` that I was not assigning `teacherQuery`. Fixed code looks like this and works fine:

```
if(loadCourses)
{
    teacherQuery = teacherQuery.Include(t => t.Courses);
}
```

Also would like to mention a [useful link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597760/what-effects-can-the-virtual-keyword-have-in-entity-framework-4-1-poco-code-fi) that @VidmantasBlazevicius provided. It contains answers on how `virtual` keyword affects your entities.