# ASP NET Core MVC Models / Foreign Key Assignment

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to assign foreign keys to multiple models that I am working with and can't seem to figure out the proper way of doing this.

For this example, all classes are in the Models namespace.

**Model-A.cs**

```
public class ModelA {
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "ID-FROM-A")]
    public int id { get; set; }
    
    public string name { get; set; }
    
    public string connection { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

**Model-B.cs**

```
public class ModelA {
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "ID-FROM-B")]
    public int id { get; set; }
    
    public string name { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("ID-FROM-A")] <--- ??? 
    public int idFromA { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

**Model-C.cs**

```
public class ModelA {
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "ID-FROM-C")]
    public int id { get; set; }
    
    public string name { get; set; }
    
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("ID-FROM-B")] <--- ??? 
    public int idFromB { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

As for the database:

```
MODELA                     MODELB                    MODELC
______                     ______                    ______
id (key)   <- 1 --|        id (key)  <- 1 --|        id (key)
name              |-- M -> model_A_Id       |-- M -> model_B_Id
connection                 ...                       ...
...
```

ModelA to ModelB is a one-to-many and ModelB to ModelC is a one-to-many.

I know there has to be a way to connect these models with foreign keys, in C#, but I am just not connecting the dots here.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify navigation properties. For example, where ModelB has a foreign key for ModelA with 1 to many relationship, you can add a collection of ModelB to Model A like this:

```
public class ModelA {
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "ID-FROM-A")]
    public int id { get; set; }
    
    public string name { get; set; }
    
    public string connection { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ModelB> ModelBs { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

The use of 'virtual' for it means that it can support lazy loading and more efficient change tracking [What effect(s) can the virtual keyword have in Entity Framework 4.1 POCO Code First?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597760/what-effects-can-the-virtual-keyword-have-in-entity-framework-4-1-poco-code-fi)